# Should I update Android OS on 1.5 yrs old phone?

Tags: updates

Will it make it slower or faster?

My phone: Moto G Play (XT1607)

Not rooted.

Comment: Your question is unclear... Do you mean official OTA updates or something else? If your device rooted or modified in any way? And updates likely will not make it faster or slower, at least not noticably.

Comment: @acejavelin not sure what OTA is. Phone not rooted.

Comment: OTA - Over The Air...

Comment: If you are talking an official update provided by the manufacturer (in your case Motorola/Lenovo) the answer is nearly always yes.

Comment: I would agree, there is rarely any reason not to accept official updates from the manufacturer on a stock device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should go for it. Software update always optimises phone performance improvement in Security , Bug Fixes and may other things. I hope this will help